# When does a String that's declared frozen get allocated (if at all?)

Tags: ruby, string, string-interning

In ruby 2.2, do the following allocate new String objects or use the one that's been interned? Assume that these commands are run in the order they're given.

```
"foo".freeze
foo = "foo".freeze
foo2 = "foo"
foo2.freeze
foo3 = foo.freeze
foo4 = ["foo".freeze].first
foo5 = ["foo"].map(&:freeze).first
```

If you could provide proof of your answer that'd be great too :).

Comment: You can always check if a new object is created by asking object's `object_id` and see if it's different among those assignments.

Answer (score 1):

> In Ruby 2.1, "str".freeze is optimized by the compiler to return a
>   single shared frozen string on every invocation.

From: http://tmm1.net/ruby21-fstrings/

You can use the `object_id` method to test this yourself.

```
"foo".freeze.object_id
=> 87323600

foo = "foo".freeze
foo.object_id
=> 87323600
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"foo".freeze.object_id              # => 70148079771220
foo = "foo".freeze
foo.object_id                       # => 70148079771220
foo2 = "foo"
foo2.object_id                      # => 70148076813240
foo2.freeze
foo2.object_id                      # => 70148076813240
foo3 = foo.freeze
foo3.object_id                      # => 70148079771220
foo4 = ["foo".freeze].first
foo4.object_id                      # => 70148079771220
foo5 = ["foo"].map(&:freeze).first
foo5.object_id                      # => 70148079700740
```

So basically, you can rationalize it by two rules:

- Calling `String#freeze` will not change the object id of an already referenced string.
- Calling `String#freeze` on a literal string will reference the internalized version.

Comment: The two rules are just how I have understood, but they do not explain why the first line, `foo`, and the element in `foo4` are identical. (The result is surprising to me.)

Comment: @sawa, it does. The first line - there is nothing there. It is the first time the value will be internalized, since it's the first occurrence. The `foo` one - again, noone had a reference to `"foo"`, hence there is no problem to use the internalized version. In `foo4`, the case is the same. `String#freeze` was called before anything was done with the `"foo"` reference, unlike in the `foo5` example.

Comment: @sawa, in other words, if you reference it before you freeze it, you can't internalize it. Otherwise, you can.

Comment: I may have misunderstood how this works. Does it mean that different occurrences of a string literal with identical content have the same object id?

Comment: "if you reference it before you freeze it, you can't internalize it"--That part has been clear enough. The optimization is only effective when `freeze` is applied to a string literal.

Comment: @sawa, `foo = "wtf".freeze; bar = "wtf".freeze; baz = "wtf"; baz.freeze; foo.object_id == bar.object_id # => true; foo.object_id == baz.object_id # => false`. In other words - yes, freeze will reuse the same object when it's possible. If you freeze literal strings that is possible. If you are freezing a referenced string that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

This is really hard to say, unfortunately. YARV 2.1+ *does* perform some string interning optimizations, however, it is not clear whether those optimizations are private internal implementation details of YARV 2.1+ or an officially guaranteed feature of Ruby 2.1+ semantics, i.e. part of the Ruby 2.1+ Language Specification. The problem is: there *is* no "Ruby 2.1+ Language Specification" outside of matz's head, so there is nowhere to look up the answer.

They are described in the ChangeLog of YARV 2.1, but again, this doesn't say much: the ChangeLog freely mixes features of YARV with features of Ruby without indicating which is which.